# How to get event.target in React WITHOUT click

Tags: css, reactjs

I know how it can be done with onClick, for adding a new css class for example:

```
wheelFade = (event) => {
   event.target.classList.add('newClass');
}

render(){
    return(
       <img onClick={this.wheelFade} className="wheel1" src="wheel.png" alt=""/>
    )
   }
```

But if I want to add a class to the img tag using a setTimtOut for example how can I access the img tag without having the event.target that I do get on click?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References would work.

```
constructor(props) {
  ...
  this.image = null;
}

render() {
  return (
    <img ref={image => this.image = image} />
  )
}
```

Once rendered, you can access the element by using `this.image`